# Accesing datagridview from other form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagrid

I've got a problem in accessing a datagrid from second form I call to add data to this datagrid.
Code looks like

```
 public partial class adding : Form
{

    public adding()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void _confirmadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AlbumsDataBase.Tabela.Rows.Add("1", "XX");

    }

}
```

second form I use to add data from

```
 public partial class AlbumsDataBase
{
    //

    public void InitializeComponent()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
        System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
        System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle3 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
        System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle4 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
        System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle5 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
        System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle6 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
        System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle7 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
        System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle8 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
        System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle9 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
        System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle10 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
        this.backgroundWorker1 = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
        this.Tabela = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
        this.Number = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.ID = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.AlbumName = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.Artist = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.Genre = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.ReleaseDate = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.TracksAmount = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.AlbumLocation = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.Rating = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.add = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.Tabela)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();

        // 


    }
```

And this is my initialization of the whole Datagridview.

The error I get:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'WindowApplicationJiMPSemestr2Cs.AlbumsDataBase.Tabela'
```

And finally to question. Where is the problem? Is that property problem or some method problem? Could anyone help me ?
Thanks in advance

Yes I know I use only 2 arguments in "Rows.Add"

Comment: That error basically means what it says: you are trying to access `Tabela` as if it was static method/property, whereas it can only be accessed on an instantiated instance of that class.

Comment: How should I access that 'Tabela' then?